# Angular JS and ng-model not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am a newbie at Angular JS and this is what I started with:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.displayName = 'Hello';

}]);
```

`user` is used to gather the data in the input fields in my steps `<input type='text' ng-model='user.name'>` and when I call it like so `{{user.name}}` what is inside the input text appears in a next step.

My question is how do I get `$scope.displayName` to display on my page.

```
<p ng-model="displayName"></p>
<p>{{displayName}}</p>
<p><input type='text' ng-model='displayName'></p>
```

I have tried all of these and none seem to work. Please help.

here is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fc7KZ/

Comment: You wrote `ng-modle` wrong

Comment: they still didnt work even when i changed them to ng-model

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle or plunker demo to review

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fc7KZ/

Comment: Updated your fiddle did not have angular library included http://jsfiddle.net/Fc7KZ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you added the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` attributes to your html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="WizardController">
<p ng-model="displayName"></p>
<p>{{displayName}}</p>
<p><input type='text' ng-model='displayName'></p>
</body>
```

**Update 1:**

Your js fiddle did not have angular library here is the version corrected:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fc7KZ/2/

Comment: nope I have those in place, but it did make me check twice.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `angular-wizard`.  Your Fiddle doesn't include [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Lodash](http://lodash.com/), which are both [pre-requisites of that project](https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard#dependencies). I'm guess your local code doesn't either, if not then that's your problem.